# What is the propper way of saving Resource references in between Unity runs

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, reference, resources

In my RPG, I have implemented dynamic system for item creation:

When I want to create a new item at runtime, I base its parameters(icon, name, ...) from a prefab that serves as item database and has such values for all items. I take those values and put them into an newly created class that serves as item in-game representation.

Then, when I want to save, I use JSON to save the data to harddrive. Now the problem comes:

JSON will save parameters like icon as `InstanceID`. From research I did, it seems `InstanceId` might change in between Unity runs.

**So what is the propper way of saving resource references at runtime to disk and loading them in between Unity runs?**

Comment: You should save the data that you are interested on, and later create it again reading it from the JSON.

Comment: That is what I am doing. But as I said, JSON representation or an icon or other resources is its `InstanceId`. That might change in-between Unity runs AFAIK.

Comment: You should make your own JSON for all the data, icon, position, status, etc

So your json contains "icon" :"image.png"

Comment: You can't serialize GameObjects, so you will need to serialize the information *about* those GameObjects, then when deserializing, create a new GameObject and apply that data to it.